# get an ideal size for background image of a div that has no set width or height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following Markup:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-personal-user clearfix">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered">
                    <img src="img/avatar04.png" class="profile-avatar">
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Where `.jumbotron-personal-user` has:

```
.jumbotron-personal-user{ margin: 0 -15px !important; background: url(../img/blur-background08.jpg) center center fixed no-repeat;}
```

but the jumbotron itself has no fixed width or height, only bootstrap's default styles:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

This is a blurred background, so more or less, it would't look bad. How can I let the user know what should the ideal measurements of an image be so that he can choose/make one so that it ca fit?

Here's a picture of the interface of the profile:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of jquery plugins that can be use to crop images after uploading http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/ . OR you can create a script that determine whether the image's size can be used as cover and return a warning if the resolution/size is not good as photo. OR indicate the suggested image size at the upload window. You can also use CSS's `background-size` - I used it before for my project's cover photo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use one plugin there to make this hassle free, as I don't have much time before I present the mockup.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with that. It's a nice website btw.

Comment: Thanks, comments like that make my day as a web designer. :)